# iPhone SDK 3.0 deprecation of UITableViewCell .text

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Came across an SDK3.0 deprecation that I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out. If my declaration of

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *rowImage;
```

does not work, nor

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImage *rowImage;
```

and I

```
@synthesize rowImage;
```

Do I need to write my own setter because `@synthesize` will not properly handle this?

```
<hr>

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:RootViewControllerCell] autorelease];


// Dpericated in SDK 3.0 <br>
//<br>
//cell.text = controller.title;<br>
//cell.image = controller.rowImage;<br>

// Using what the documentation says to use 
Error===> cell.textLabel = controller.title;<br>
Error===> cell.imageView = controller.rowImage;<br>

Error: Object cannot be set - Either readonly property or no setter found.
```

Hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use the non-deprecated:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RootViewControllerCell] autorelease];
```

Then:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[controller title]]; <br>
[[cell imageView] setImage:[controller rowImage]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the usual .-syntax:

```
cell.textLabel.text = controller.title;
```